# How you organize the interaction between Angular app and Xero OAuth2.0?

Tags: node.js, angular, xero-api

I am building Angular app that should interact with Xero API. Xero doesn't provide any SDK for Typescript (https://developer.xero.com/documentation/libraries/overview), but Node JS SDK seems to be the most useful lib for my task. But I am in stuck in how to organize the workflow between my app and their https://github.com/XeroAPI/xero-node-oauth2-app . I mean - I'd like to have some advises from the person who has already made similar apps (Angular + Xero) on following questions:
1) in this guide https://developer.xero.com/documentation/oauth2/auth-flow they say that user should open the page with URL like `https://login.xero.com/identity/connect/authorize?...` - but is there any way to make user log in without UI? If not -
2)  how this process can be made in my case? In my Angular app I can make a button 'Log in to Xero' that will open new window:

```
window.open(xeroUrl, 'xeroAuth', 'location=yes,height=770,width=620,scrollbars=yes,status=yes');
```

where User log in, provide access to his organisation. The session tokens are created on the backend. But what next? How can I pass those tokens to my Angular app from that new window and then use them to make calls to Xero API?
3) Is the way to open new window for loggin in to Xero suitable for this case or maybe there is a better way to log in to Xero and get session tokens?
Thanks in advance for help.

Comment: On the logging in without UI, you can have a look at this video and use XOAuth - it needs the first login to be done via the UI, but you can store and refresh the tokens after that: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Zcf_64yreVI&t=5s - I've no idea about Angular, having watched this video I just use HTTP Get and Post calls directly to the endpoints.

Comment: i know it is not related but do you know any way to open this xero in a modal and not in a new window? we have our ui in angular and instead of a new window we want to open it in a modal popup for performance of angular issue we have

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, SPAs are not compatible with the Xero API.

You'll need a web server to manage your local session (OAuth flow, storage of Xero API tokens), and for your interactions with the Xero API.

While SPAs are a tempting option (they are convenient from a deployment point of view), there are changes coming to how browsers handle cross-site cookies, which break how SPAs perform session management.

I'd suggest reading https://leastprivilege.com/2020/03/31/spas-are-dead/ for more information and a discussion of the implications. The authors of the article created [OIDC Client JS](https://github.com/IdentityModel/oidc-client-js/) which is a great library for doing PKCE-based SPA auth in the browser, though it's only useful for same-domain applications now thanks to the impending browser cookie changes.

Further to this, the Xero API does not support CORS, so even once you complete the OAuth flow, the browser would be prevented from performing API requests from your Angular SPA.

To answer the specific questions:

1) The user will need to log in to Xero and grant consent for your app the first time they use your application. If you're storing server-side refresh tokens after the initial consent, your user will only need to log in to your local session, either via Xero SSO or another mechanism (user/password).

2) To create the initial Authorisation Request, it's best to use the node.js starter app. It will manage the OAuth redirect flow for you (it uses the excellent [openid-client](https://github.com/panva/node-openid-client) open source package for this).